# How to get DataLakeServiceClient instance having access token

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, access-token, azure-data-lake

I perform request to https://login.microsoftonline.com//oauth2/token as described:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow

As response I have got AccessToken like: "eyJ0eXAiOiJ.....X1o3BncIo5WA"

Having that AccessToken I need to get connected DataLakeServiceClient instance.
I read all methods of getting the client as described in:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/java/sdk/identity-service-principal-auth
but there no one which could be used with  ready-made AccessToken.

Does anybody know the proper way to get the DataLakeServiceClient by AccessToken ?
It is key : The ready-made AccessToken must be used.

Answer (score 1):

The way I have dealt with this situation is to create a class that derives from [`TokenCredential`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.core.tokencredential?view=azure-dotnet) class, pass access token in its constructor and then return an object of type `AccessToken` in `GetToken` method.

Something like:

```
/// <summary>
/// Creates a token credential class using an access token.
/// </summary>
public class AccessTokenCredential : TokenCredential
{
  /// <summary>
  /// Creates an instance of <see cref="AccessTokenCredential"/>.
  /// </summary>
  /// <param name="accessToken">
  /// JWT encoded access token.
  /// </param>
  public AccessTokenCredential(string accessToken)
  {
      AccessToken = accessToken;
  }
  
  /// <summary>
  /// Gets the access token.
  /// </summary>
  private string AccessToken { get; }

  /// <summary>
  /// 
  /// </summary>
  /// <param name="requestContext"></param>
  /// <param name="cancellationToken"></param>
  /// <returns></returns>
  public override ValueTask<AccessToken> GetTokenAsync(TokenRequestContext requestContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
  {
      return new ValueTask<AccessToken>(GetAccessToken());
  }

  /// <summary>
  /// 
  /// </summary>
  /// <param name="requestContext"></param>
  /// <param name="cancellationToken"></param>
  /// <returns></returns>
  public override AccessToken GetToken(TokenRequestContext requestContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
  {
      return GetAccessToken();
  }

  /// <summary>
  /// Validates access token and returns <see cref="AccessToken"/>.
  /// </summary>
  /// <returns>
  /// <see cref="AccessToken"/>.
  /// </returns>
  /// <exception cref="ArgumentException">
  /// Access token is invalid.
  /// </exception>
  private AccessToken GetAccessToken()
  {
      JwtSecurityToken token = new JwtSecurityToken(AccessToken);
      return new AccessToken(AccessToken, token.ValidTo);
  }
}
```

You can then use [`DataLakeServiceClient(Uri, TokenCredential)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.files.datalake.datalakeserviceclient.-ctor?view=azure-dotnet#azure-storage-files-datalake-datalakeserviceclient-ctor(system-uri-azure-core-tokencredential)) constructor override.